SSRS Error calculating Max on a group with Scope
We built the following report in SSRS
It has two groups, the top one called perf_group and table1_Details_Group.
The detail section, is generally closed and only toggled open when detailed information is necessary. All the calculations live on the top level.

The last column without the header is what we are working on and what is generating errors. We've tried it as such
=Max((Count(Fields!seat_locations.Value, "perf_group") - Sum(IIf(Fields!status.Value = "pending", 1, 0), "perf_group")) - 4, 0, "perf_group")
and as such
=Max((Count(Fields!seat_locations.Value, "perf_group") - Sum(IIf(Fields!status.Value = "pending", 1, 0), "perf_group")) - 4, 0)
We need to get this work on this group for the team, but we keep getting the below errors.

Error 1:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       [rsInvalidAggregateScope] The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox24.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.
Error 2
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       [rsRecursiveAggregateOfAggregate] The Value expression for the textrun 'Textbox24.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]' has an outer aggregate that specifies the recursive flag.  Outer aggregates that specify the recursive flag cannot contain nested aggregates.

I assume perf_group is the name of a row group and the the name is identical including case? If so then try taking parts of you expression (e.g. the count() ) and add those into columns to make sure each part of the expression works before you combine them into 1 bigger expression. Also, if the expression is in the perf_group row group, you should not need to specify it at all, the expression will be evaluated in the context of the textbox it resides in.
